# border с помощью маски

Tags: html, css

На вход у нас идет изображение, и как можно через маску дать ей градиентный бордер, да знаю что можно через `border-image` и `border transparent` но в моем случае это не подходит так как с бека приходит только картинка и нельзя дать ей родителя. Как и псевдоэлемент, так как img не может с ними работать[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая связь у «с бека приходит только картинка» и «нельзя дать ей родителя»?

Comment: если дать ей блок родителя и ему класс то такая граница очень легко делается, а я в данном случае ограничен лишь тегом img

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сгенерировать svg рамки нужного размера и сделать на подобии как в примере ниже(при условии, что вы можете поставить gradient на background блока)

```
-webkit-mask-image: url(http://yoksel.github.io/Sandbox/img/tiles/tile-transparent-black.png);
-webkit-mask-repeat: space;
-webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-mask-size: 100% 100%;
```

Если border 1px я бы советовал градиентом пренебречь и воспользоваться старым-добрым outline:

```
outline: 1px solid #87b7bc;
outline-offset: -10px;
```